# How to put the action button when using the "snackBar.openFromComponent()" method in MatSnackBar?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I using MatSnackBar for notifications and I would like to have an action button in the snack-bar. How do I insert one when I am using 
***"snackBar.openFromComponent()"*** method?

Here is [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2nc51?file=app/snack-bar-component-example.ts)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51650413/9953550) I was able to solve my problem.

Here is a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2nc51-pufmjy?file=app/snack-bar-component-example.ts) with the added action button.

Comment: Thanks so much for the simple example.  The key piece that I was stuck on was the necessity of injecting the **snackBarRef** into the constructor of the custom component.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the action button directly to **snack-bar-component-example-snack.html** in the stackblitz link that you have attached.